# File not found Exception in References of MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I start up ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio, I get this error:

> File not found exception wasn't handled in the user code    An
>   exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Razor,     Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its     dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Check if `System.Web.Razor` is present in your `References` folder and if it is present check if the version is `2.0.0.0`

Comment: IT DOES PRESENT. And still errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As it seems, @alorika's answer was the correct one (Missing reference to `System.Web.Razor`)

**Old answer:**

Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Which version of MVC? What I would try as first is to repair the installation. Just go to Control panel -> Installed programs -> Select VS and click on change/repair.

On the window that opens, select repair and let the program run.
[image: VS repair]

If that doesn't help, go again to all programs and again select VS and then click on repair. But this time, in the VS window, which opens select modify and make sure, that "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" is checked (if it is not, check it and hit "Update"):

[image: VS modify]

Comment: What did you try to do to fix the issue @AgentFire